# Fatal error. Internal CLR error. (0x80131 506) on dotnet build for a specific project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, containers, podman

I am working on an asp.net Core web api project hosted within a container on a podman vm machine.

If I do the following to build using my Dockerfile everything works:

```
podman build -t <myprojectname>?:latest .
```

Followed by:

```
podman run --rm -it <myprojectname>:latest
```

I get the expected host info:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app/
```

However,

If I run the exact same `dotnet build` command I'm using in the Dockerfile manually on the console I get this:

```
 error : Fatal error. Internal CLR error. (0x80131
506) [C:\[my-folder]\<myprojectname>\<myprojectname>.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.NetCore.Analyzers.Interop
Services.PlatformCompatibilityAnalyzer+<>c__DisplayClass34_0.<AnalyzeOperationBlock>b__1(Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.Opera
tionBlockAnalysisContext) [C:\[my-folder]\<myprojectname>\<myprojectname>.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error :    at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.
AnalyzerExecutor+<>c__54`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7
798e]].<ExecuteBlockActions>b__54_1(System.ValueTuple`2<System.Action`1<Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.OperationBlockAnalysis
Context>,Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Diagnostics.OperationBlockAnalysisContext>) [C:\[my-folder]\<myprojectname>\<myprojectname>.c
sproj]
...
```

This is an issue ***only*** for the container project. Any other asp.net Core project / solution builds fine using the CLI.

I also asked a colleague to clone the repository and he gets the same thing, so it's unlikely that it's [my] machine related.

I have the following SDKs installed:

```
.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.413 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
  7.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
```

I can't avoid not having 7* because it seems to come with Visual Studio 2022.

**Any pointers what the cause might be of this very specific issue and how to solve it?**

Comment: [Have you searched the GitHub repo?](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues)

Comment: I get the feeling this is something new. I just ran into this today. You can check here what I believe is the issue. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/91695

Answer (score 0):

I get the feeling this is something new. I just ran into this today. You can check here what I believe is the issue - my dotnet sdk version of 7.0.4. https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/91695

It happens to me when running dotnet publish. A bunch of error text including:
dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets(80,5): error : Fatal error. Internal CLR error
. (0x80131506)

I created a global.json file as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/versions/selection in a project folder of my solution I was running dotnet publish on.

all I put in the file was
{
"sdk": {
"version": "6.0.407"
}
}

When I attempted to run initially with value "6.0.0" I got the following message:

Publishing .NETCore app
The command could not be loaded, possibly because:

- You intended to execute a .NET application:                                                                               The application 'publish' does not exist.                                                                           * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:                                                                               A compatible .NET SDK was not found.                                                                                                                                                                                                      Requested SDK version: 6.0.0                                                                                            global.json file: xxx\global.json                                                                                                                                                 Installed SDKs:                                                                                                         6.0.407 [xxx\dotnet\sdk]                                                                                   7.0.400 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]

Install the [6.0.0] .NET SDK or update [xxx\global.json] to match an installed SDK.

Learn about SDK resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/sdk-not-found

So I changed the global.json to use the older version I had installed and was able to dotnet publish.

Comment: Just to clarify, something new as in a bug in the latest dotnet SDKs?

Comment: That is how it was reading to me in the GitHub issue I've linked there. There seems to be some talk about fixing it as well as setting this as a work around. I have not tried it: "Setting DOTNET_TieredCompilation = 1 seems to fix the issue"